# angular how to set variable value from database when clicking on html element?

Tags: javascript, angular

iam working with angular, i have database table for the brands of my ecommerce project
and this table contains two columns, the first for the id and the second for the name of the brand, i used *ngFor to display the brands names for as list items like this

```
<ul class="d-flex list-unstyled justify-content-around w-50 mx-auto mt-5">
    <li *ngFor="let brand of brands">{{ brand.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

in the typescript file i have variable named brand_id and i need when i click on specific list item the brand_id variable value sets to this list item brand_id column value, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try next code:

```
<ul class="d-flex list-unstyled justify-content-around w-50 mx-auto mt-5">
    <li *ngFor="let brand of brands" (click)="onSaveId(brand.id)">{{ brand.name }}</li>
</ul>
```